# Numpy equivalent of zip with rolled 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

I have a list of 2D coordinates as NumPy array, e.g.

```
x = np.asarray([[0, 1],
                [1, 2],
                [2, 3]])
```

of shape `(3,2)`.

Now I want to zip this array with `np.roll(x, 1)` to obtain coordinate pairs to draw lines between (including the line from the last to the first element. The order of the lines does not matter.

I've already found a solution with the standard Python zip:

```
>>> np.asarray(list(zip(list(x[-1:]) + list(x[:-1]), x)))
array([[[2, 3],
        [0, 1]],
       [[0, 1],
        [1, 2]],
       [[1, 2],
        [2, 3]]])
```

How can I use the numpy functions without conversion to Python lists in order to obtain this result?

My attempts so far at doing it with NumPy failed miserably, for example:

```
>>> np.dstack([x, np.roll(x, 1)])
array([[[0, 3],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [3, 2]]])
```

*Edit:* This is not an attempt to create combinations of *x* with any other array so the suggested duplicate is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand why that's your desired output, but here is the dstack version you were trying to get:

```
>>> np.transpose(np.dstack([np.roll(x, 1, axis=0), x]), axes=(0,2,1))
array([[[2, 3],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 3]]])
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was totally missing the `axes` option to dstack. The output means "draw line from (2,3) to (0,1), draw line from (0,1) to (1,2) etc". If x contains all the points of a polygon, this will draw the polygon.

Comment: I am passing axes to transpose, not to dstack.

Comment: Oh... that's why I was missing it :-) Thanks. Certainly I learned something from that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with creating such rolled indices and then indexing -

```
In [18]: x            # Input array
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])

In [19]: n = x.shape[0]

In [20]: x[np.mod(np.arange(n)[:,None] + [n-1,0],n)]
Out[20]: 
array([[[2, 3],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 3]]])
```